# Best approach for migrating database schema of shared database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-design, architecture

I am currently struggling to find a way to migrate to a new database schema for a database shared by multiple applications, while keeping applications working with the old schema intact.

There are multiple applications performing CRUD operations on the shared database, using a self-written ORM-like library. The main problems I see with this architecture are:

- Each application implements its own business logic with a lot of code being redundant or code which should do the same in every application but is implemented differently and therfore hard to maintain
- Since each application works directly with the ORM-library the other applications cannot know when some data was changed by another application without monitoring/polling the database for changes
- The ORM-library does implement only limited concurrency, no transactions and is relatively slow

To solve the redundancy/inconsistency problems I am thinking about implementing a layered architecture.

- Service Layer
- Business Layer
- Data Access Layer
- Database

The applications then communicate with a SOAP web service on the service layer.
The service layer uses the business layer to perform validation and apply business logic. The business layer uses the data access layers repositories.
I am hoping to be able to also use the business layer in the client applications, with another repository implementation, which does not access the database directly but via the SOAP web service.

To solve the other problems I was hoping to use Entity Framework instead of the selfmade ORM-library. But the schema of the database is made in a kind of generic way. Meaning for each machine added to the database (database stores facility data) several machine specific tables are added. This results in redundant tables, named *[machinename]_[tablename]*. As far as I know, Entity Framework or any other ORM cannot deal with that (its poor design anyway, probably meant to speed queries up).

The plan would be to migrate to another database schema, but the problem with that is that all the applications using the database need to be changed to use the new schema/SOAP web service. This cannot happen from one day to another therefore it would be best if I can keep some of the applications unchanged, but still work on the only one database. And then later deal with reimplementing the other applications to use the web service.

I already thought about using views to simulate the old schema, so that the old applications can still work with the changed schema, but unfortunately the selfmade ORM does not support working with views.

I don't expect anyone to present me a solution but rather some basic approaches and/or ideas to improve the overall architecture of the system.

Comment: I think you have two problems 1) Create a shared library/service layer including DB layer encapsulation for all legacy apps to use 2) update said apps to use the library/service.    I suspect 2) will be a mammoth task irrespective of whether you use SOA or not!   However, removing data connections in clients and moving to the backend in whatever form is a good step in the right direction for scalability and security

Comment: This kind of sums up my problem. And it's exactly that mammoth task I am facing and cannot think of a way to workaround.

Comment: Agreed.   I wish you well good sir